# Mismatching @next/swc version, detected: 14.0.3 while Next.js is on 13.5.3

Tags: next.js, docker-compose, dockerfile

When I try to run my docker image, I get this error that says Mismatching @next/swc version, detected: 14.0.3 while Next.js is on 13.5.3. which gives me an internal server error when I try to access localhost:3000( this is not from the backend as I have not connected the backend yet), I have also tried installing @next/swc with the version recommended, but it throws an error "npm ERR! 404  '@next/swc@*' is not in this registry.", even though i have configured it to "https://registry.npmjs.org/"

How can I solve the issue of type mismatch so I can run my docker without getting that error, and also view my website content on the browser without having to get an internal server error?